# How do I bake this correctly?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking

Ok, I've been struggling with this all day,
I'm trying to bake the materials of the mesh on the left into a single image texture.

Everything looks good in the original one, but the baked texture always comes out flat and it just looks terrible.

Is there anything I can do to bake the one on the left into an image texture that actually looks like the original?

(Original on the left, baked texture on the right)
[image]

Comment: What are the bake options? Have you baked the lights? if yes the one on the right is lighted twice.

Comment: Combined bake type, Direct lighting, Diffuse, and Glossy. Yeah right one is lighted twice, but it' still not getting the shininess or the detail of the left one.

Comment: If it is to have a texture, only diffuse and color? But that depends on what you finally want.

Comment: Ok, it turns out I need to bake them all separately and then bake them together afterwards. It works better for me doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, tell me if i'm wrong (believe me I'd love to be wrong on this) but it turns out what I was trying to do is not possible because the diffuse texture is flat, and even when faking the normals, it still looks unrealistic. But it works if you bake them separately with just diffuse and color.